# Degree $n$ field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$th root of a rational number

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Suppose we have a field extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n.$ Is it always the case that $K=\mathbb{Q}(d^{\frac{1}{n}})$ for some $d\in \mathbb{Q}$?

I was thinking about this because I realised for $n=2$ this is always the case (i.e., any quadratic number field is in the form of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some $d\in \mathbb{Z}$). I was wondering is this false for all $n$, $n\geq 3$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is false for $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ for instance.

Comment: You're asking whether every finite extension is a [simple radical extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension). I don't think so but I have no proof. I seem to recall this being discused here but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Kummer theory tells us that if $K$ contains the $n^{th}$ roots of unity then there is a bijection between cyclic galois extensions of degree $n$ and subgroups of $K^*/(K^*)^n$ for order $n$ given precisely by taking $n^{th}$ roots of (representitives of) elements of the latter (you also need to assume $n$ is coprime to the characteristic)

Comment: @lhf yes, which is why i was only mentioning it as a comment. But it shows why the phenomenon OP mentioned is true with $n = 2$.

Comment: This is untrue for all $p$ prime. Take a root of a generic quintic and adjoin this, this is not solvable by radicals, so can't be given as an extension by a $5^{th}$ root

Comment: Any cubic with Galois group cyclic of order $3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Yeah you are right, I am thinking does this question have something to do with $S_n$ being solvable? If that is the case the statement is false for $n\geq 5$

Comment: Yes, choose any degree $n$ polynomial with galois group $S_n$, then adjoin a root. As lulu points out, it is untrue for $3$, and lhf gave a counterexample for $4$. Basically all this boils down to the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ only contains the $2^{nd}$ roots of $1$, and all degree $2$ extensions are galois, hence Kummer theory.

Comment: @lulu Hey, I like your counterexample but I don't really understand why, could you please elaborate a little bit further please? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @JustWandering Hint: if you just adjoin a $3^{rd}$ root, the extension won't be galois.

Comment: More generally, note that, for $p>2$, the number field obtained by adding the real root of $\sqrt[p] d$ is *never* Galois, as it does not contain the other roots of $x^p-d$  Hence, if you can exhibit a Galois field of degree $p$, it can not be of this form.

Comment: Given a field $K$ and an integer $n \ge 2$, Serge Lang's book "Algebra" contains an instructive $sufficient$ condition for $X^n -d$ to be irreducible over $K$, see chap. VIII, §9.